# Inject content from Swift code to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I am developing an app which uses `WKWebView` to show an html document. I want to inject content from my Swift code to this document. This is what I tried:

```
var myString: String

// ... Code which assigns some value to myString

targetView.evaluateJavaScript("injector.injectSnippet(\(myString);", completionHandler: nil)
```

This works exactly as I expect so long as the argument in the JavaScript function call is hardcoded:

```
targetView.evaluateJavaScript("injector.injectSnippet(\"Hello World\");", completionHandler: nil)
```

The `injector` object is in a JavaScript file which I have already added to the web view's user controller:

```
var injector = (function () {
    "use strict"
    var msgBox;

    var injectSnippet = function (test) {        
        msgBox.innerHTML = "Received value: " + test;
    }

    var init = function () {        
        // Create msgBox div element and insert it into the document            
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        injectSnippet: injectSnippet
    };

} ());

injector.init();
```

How do I get content into the WKWebView?

I went through the Apple docs *WebKit Objective-C Programming Guide* and *WebKit DOM Programming Topics* but I don't understand what sort of `WebView` class they are using there. Both `WKWebView` and `UIWebView` don't have all the API they use in these documents.

Is there some way to manipulate the DOM directly in Swift? I get the sense that [WebScriptObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebScriptObject_Class/index.html) might be what I'm looking for but can I use this with `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using evaluateJavaScript, you need to inject the value into the javascript string.

Something like

```
var jsTemplate = "injector.injectSnippet(\"%@\");"
var js = String(format:jsTemplate , myString)
```

Comment: How do I use WebScriptObject with WKWebView? In the Apple docs, they do 'id win = [webView windowScriptObject];' but neither UIWebView not WKWebView has this property as far as I've seen. Could you point me at some resources? Google turns up mostly introductory tutorials and references to the older Apple documentation. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sorry, WebScriptObject isn't available on iOS, I had it mixed up with something unrelated.